# SVN Export latest modified/added files in Windows

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to export **only** the files that is being modified/newly added from SVN.

There is lots of solutions in stackoverflow and google, but all of them are linux.
I need the solutions that runs on windows.

Is there a svn command to do this with ease?
There were few samples that is created in "Bash" and not in window command line.

Or perhaps with Window Batch apps?

---

Tried using a sample shown in http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-06/0977.shtml

I've installed GnuWin32 to use some unix command, created a window batch app but stucked in the replacing 
http://www.mydomain.com/trunk/**client\default.aspx.vb** with **client/default.aspx.vb**

at this part of the code

> SET CALL URL=!%FILE%:\=/!

Code (test.bat)

```
...
echo Exporting changed files 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /F %%A in (files.txt) do ( 
REM Changes the backslashes to forward slashes for the svn:// url 
SET CALL FILE=%%A% 
SET CALL URL=!%FILE%:\=/!

rem CALL SET URL=%FILE:\=/%
REM Export the file from the repository to the patch directory 
rem svn export %SVN%/%URL% %PATCH%\%%A 
echo
echo "FILE1" %FILE% 
echo "FILE2" !FILE!
echo "URL1" !URL!
echo "URL2" %URL%
echo "TARGET" %PATCH%\%FILE%
) 
ENDLOCAL 
...
```

Output:

```
"FILE1" client\default.aspx.vb
"FILE2" client\defualt.aspx.vb
"URL1" http://www.mydomain.com/trunk/client\default.aspx.vb
"URL2" http://www.mydomain.com/trunk/client\default.aspx.vb
"TARGET" .\temp \client\default.aspx.vb
```

Could anyone point out what i did wrong?
Thank you in advance. :)

Edit: Forgot to include the output of the (files.txt)

> M       C:\ci\project\www.mydomain.com\client\default.aspx.vb

Answer (score 1):

Not a final solution (can't get it without *at least some of* Unix-ports to Win), but starting point:

> svn log -c 4479 -v -q

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4479 | pavel.pimenov | 2010-08-26 00:54:46 +0600 (Чт, 26 авг 2010)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/FlylinkDC_version.xml
   M /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/StrongDC_version.xml
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/images/flylinkdc-chip-2008.jpg
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/images/mainmenu/clip0060.png
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/images/settings/adv_rating.jpg
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/images/vip.jpg
   M /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/index.html
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/script
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/script/FeedForAll_XMLParser.inc.php
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/script/rss2html.php
   A /branches/www.flylinkdc.ru/script/sample-template.html
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

you have to:

- Use -c HEAD instead of revision number in my example
- grep "newline-3spaces-A|M-space" output

Answer (score 0):

In windows, as nearly as I can tell you have to download a [svn client](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to export svn links.

[Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is one of the SVN client to update/commit/export to/from SVN.

Comment: Hi ykartal, thank you for the response. But I need to create a script or come up with a command to integrate with Jenkins CI server. I'm currently using Tortoise SVN as my SVN client, thats why i'm having problem of coming up with the script for command line script to achieve it.